# SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 84 using Selenium

Tags: python, windows, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I cannot get my Chromedriver to work and have downloaded a few different versions with no change in the output error. My code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver= webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/chromedriver.exe')

driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

and the output in the kernel is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Market Bot.py", line 11, in <module>
    driver= webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/chromedriver.exe')

  File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)

  File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)

  File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)

  File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

  File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 84
```

How do I get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check what version of chrome you're running, as of writing this version 83 is the stable public release. You can check by going to this url: chrome://settings/help
2. Download *the same version* of the chrome driver as the version of chrome you have, so if you're on chrome version 83, download the chrome driver with version 83. You can get chrome drivers here: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
3. Point your script at the correct chrome driver version.